# MySqlConnector.MySqlException Duplicate entry for key PRIMARY with accents

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, mariadb

On a MariaDB database (10.6) I meet the following error with different values for key:

> MySqlConnector.MySqlException : 'Duplicate entry 'GUÈN10' for key 'PRIMARY''

When I check the inserted data, I see that there is no other duplicate but one without accents: 'GUEN10'.

It seems PRIMARY KEY comparison is ignoring accents.

The database is created by script with:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Then tables are created with EFcore with:

```
// Global builder
modelBuilder.HasCharSet("utf8mb4", DelegationModes.ApplyToAll);
// Entity builder
builder.HasCharSet("utf8mb4", true);
```

If I check information_schema I can see that the column is created with the right charset/collate:

```
COLUMN_NAME          CHARACTER_SET_NAME   COLLATION_NAME         
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- 
EntityId             utf8mb4              utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Insert is done with a MySqlCommand which I prefix by `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';`.

I also tried with utf8mb3 / utf8mb3_general_ci which is the default for the database without success.

How can I fix PRIMARY KEY comparison to consider accents?

Comment: I believe that case-insensitive collations are also accent-insensitive.

Comment: So don't use `_ci` if you need to be able to insert values that are the same except for accents.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know 'ci' was case insensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The utf8mb4 ci collations in 10.6 don't handle (case sensitive) accents. You either have to use a binary collation or wait for MariaDB 10.8 to use accent sensitive collations.

MySQL 8.0 already supports utf8mb4_0900_as_cs collation.

See also: [MDEV-20912](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20912), [MDEV-27009](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27009)

Comment: Ok, for the moment I will use a binary collation on primary keys : `if (prop.IsPrimaryKey()) prop.SetCollation("utf8mb4_bin");`